# Update array of objects after comparing to another array of object Mule 4

Tags: arrays, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a requirement where I have update the value of object of array based on the the values of object of another array.
Below are Input arrays and the expected Output.
Values of FieldName2 and FieldName3 in Input 2 are updated with the Value of "value" in Input 1 where ids are matching.

**Input 1 :**

```
[
        {
                "id": 123,
                "key": "Dummy1",
                "value": "20"
        },
        {
                "id": 123,
                "key": "Dummy2",
                "value": "50"
        },
        {
                "id": 123,
                "key": "Dummy3",
                "value": "100"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "key": "Dummy2",
                "value": "40"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "key": "Dummy3",
                "value": "90"
        }
]
```

**Input 2 :**

```
[
        {
                "id": 123,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "20",
                "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
                "FieldName3": "0"
        },
        {
                "id": 123,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "20",
                "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
                "FieldName3": "Dummy2"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "10",
                "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
                "FieldName3": "0"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "10",
                "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
                "FieldName3": "Dummy2"
        }
]
```

**Output :**

```
[
        {
                "id": 123,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "20",
                "FieldName2": "20",
                "FieldName3": "0"
        },
        {
                "id": 123,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "20",
                "FieldName2": "20",
                "FieldName3": "50"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "10",
                "FieldName2": "10",
                "FieldName3": "0"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "10",
                "FieldName2": "10",
                "FieldName3": "40"
        }
]
```

Comment: Why the value of the field is sometimes used update the name and others the value? What's the logic?

Comment: @aled actually these values are used for comparison purposes, my actual requirement is a bit different where the values can be dynamic or can be a hard-coded value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inp1 = [
        {
                "id": 123,
                "key": "Dummy1",
                "value": "20"
        },
        {
                "id": 123,
                "key": "Dummy2",
                "value": "50"
        },
        {
                "id": 123,
                "key": "Dummy3",
                "value": "100"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "key": "Dummy2",
                "value": "40"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "key": "Dummy3",
                "value": "90"
        }
]

var inp2 = [
        {
                "id": 123,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "20",
                "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
                "FieldName3": "0"
        },
        {
                "id": 123,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "20",
                "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
                "FieldName3": "Dummy2"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "10",
                "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
                "FieldName3": "0"
        },
        {
                "id": 789,
                "FieldName": "Dummy1",
                "FieldValue": "10",
                "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
                "FieldName3": "Dummy2"
        }
]
var inpGrouped =inp1 groupBy ($.id ++ $."key")
---
inp2 map {
      "id":$.id ,
      "FieldName": $.FieldName,
      "FieldValue": $.FieldValue ,
      "FieldName2": if(inpGrouped[($.id ++ $.FieldName2)].value[0] != null) inpGrouped[($.id ++ $.FieldName2)].value[0] else $.FieldName2,
      "FieldName3": if(inpGrouped[($.id ++ $.FieldName3)].value[0] != null) inpGrouped[($.id ++ $.FieldName3)].value[0] else $.FieldName3
}
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "FieldName": "Dummy1",
    "FieldValue": "20",
    "FieldName2": "20",
    "FieldName3": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "FieldName": "Dummy1",
    "FieldValue": "20",
    "FieldName2": "20",
    "FieldName3": "50"
  },
  {
    "id": 789,
    "FieldName": "Dummy1",
    "FieldValue": "10",
    "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
    "FieldName3": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": 789,
    "FieldName": "Dummy1",
    "FieldValue": "10",
    "FieldName2": "Dummy1",
    "FieldName3": "40"
  }
]
```

PS: In this output corresponding to id `789` there is no value in the input (inp1 ) for "Dummy1". As a result you would seed the output as "Dummy1" as well.